# Issues using newtheorem

Tags: newtheorem

I'm trying to use `\newtheorem`.

Here's my small sty file mystyle.sty

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{action}{$\checkmark$ Action}
\newtheorem{law}{$\bigodot$ Law}
\newtheorem{fact}{$\boxdot$ Fact}
\newtheorem{warn}{$\warning$ Caveat}
```

Here's the tex file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{arevmath}
\usepackage{mystyle}
\begin{document}
\section{Head}
\begin{law}
The world is round
\end{law}
\begin{fact}
\(g =99.8 m/s^2\)
\end{fact}
\begin{action}
Teach co-recursion before recursion
\end{action}
\begin{warn}
 Beware
\end{warn}
\end{document}
```

This is with package `arevmath`
[image: with arevmath]

This is without arevmath
[image: without arevmath]

So now the questions:

1. I want the warning symbol which is in `arevmath` but the general look of without `arevmath` is better. How to manage both?
2. The content is coming in italic. But the examples I find for using `newtheorem`
   it comes normal roman. Is something else wrong?? eg...
3. I picked up the eg from an inline source that uses `\makeatletter`.  I'm not at all sure how to use it except for some vague directive: use in `.tex` not in `.sty`.

Comment: As for (2) look up `\theormestyle` in the manual for `amsthm`

Comment: Unrelated: please use the `siunitx` package to format units

Comment: `\makeatletter` is not used in your MWE, and is irrelevant to questions (1) and (2). You may desire to ask question (3) separately. (But if you do so, almost certainly it will be closed as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8353/119, so you might just as well read that answer instead..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use just the symbols provided by `arevmath`, not to change all math symbols to use it.

Actually, `arevmath` uses `ams-mdbch` and we see, in `ams-mdbch.sty`,

```
\xdef\checkmark{\noexpand\mathhexbox{\hexnumber@\symmathdesignA}D8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\boxdot}{\mathbin}{mathdesignA}{"80}
```

The definition of `\bigodot` is the standard one, albeit using a different font. The command `\warning` is found in `arevsymbols.tex` and we see

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\warning}{\mathalpha}{extraup}{125} % uni26A0
```

OK, the file `ams-mdbch.sty` has

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathdesignA}{MDA}{mdbch}{b}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols} {normal}{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}
```

and in `arevmath.sty` we see

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{extraup}{U}{zavm}{m}{n}
```

Quite a chase! But we have all the ingredients. The only problem is `\bigodot`, but it can be solved.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{arevmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDA}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDA}{cmr}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\arevcheckmark}{{\usefont{MDA}{mdbch}{b}{n}\symbol{"D8}}}
\newcommand{\arevbigodot}{%
  $\vcenter{\hbox{\usefont{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}\symbol{"4A}}}$%
}
\newcommand{\arevboxdot}{{\usefont{MDA}{mdbch}{b}{n}\symbol{"80}}}
\newcommand{\arevwarning}{{\usefont{U}{zavm}{m}{n}\symbol{125}}}

\newtheorem{action}{\arevcheckmark\ Action}
\newtheorem{law}{\arevbigodot\ Law}
\newtheorem{fact}{\arevboxdot\ Fact}
\newtheorem{warn}{\arevwarning\ Caveat}

\begin{document}

\section{Head}

\begin{law}
The world is round
\end{law}

\begin{fact}
\(g =99.8 m/s^2\)
\end{fact}

\begin{action}
Teach co-recursion before recursion
\end{action}

\begin{warn}
Beware
\end{warn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I left the wrong typesetting of the units in 9.8 m/s<sup>2</sup>, fix it.

Comment: Vow ! Thats a detailed answer. I'll need a while to chase after your chase . To figure out what all youve done there. [Latex noob here]

Comment: @Rusi Not a noob here. `;-)`

Comment: Ok I got something working. I find the (nonarev) \boxdot better than the arev one.  But that works only inside math mode. So is it fine that some of these symbols are in in math some not?

Comment: My current version is put up. Thanks for the help. [I'm not completely satisfied with the (relative) sizes but this will fly for now]

Answer (score 0):

My current version thanks to egreg's help.
[Yeah the units are not proper.  But that was a red herring for me anyway to produce some mwe; not something I currently need in my actual example]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{arevmath}

\DeclareFontEncoding{MDA}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{MDA}{cmr}{m}{n}

\newcommand{\arevcheckmark}{{\usefont{MDA}{mdbch}{b}{n}\symbol{"D8}}}
%% \newcommand{\arevbigodot}{%
%%   $\vcenter{\hbox{\usefont{OMX}{mdbch}{m}{n}\symbol{"4A}}}$%
%% }

\newcommand{\arevboxdot}{{\usefont{MDA}{mdbch}{b}{n}\symbol{"80}}}
\newcommand{\arevwarning}{{\usefont{U}{zavm}{m}{n}\symbol{125}}}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{action}{\arevcheckmark\ Action}
\newtheorem{law}{\(\odot\)\ Law}
\newtheorem{fact}{\(\boxdot\)\ Fact}
\newtheorem{warn}{\arevwarning\ Caveat}

\begin{document}

\section{Head}

\begin{law}
The world is round
\end{law}

\begin{fact}
\(g =99.8 m/s^2\)
\end{fact}

\begin{action}
Teach co-recursion before recursion
\end{action}

\begin{warn}
Beware
\end{warn}
\end{document}
```